# Shut down Macbook Pro automatically after download?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macbook-pro

I have a *Late 2011* Macbook Pro.
I want it to **shut down** automatically after downloading and installing Softwares Updates and if possible, downloads through other application too (eg. Mac App Store, Google Chrome, Blizzard Game Launcher etc.)

I'm running OSX Lion {10.7.3}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install all software updates and then shut down the system, from a Terminal run:

```
sudo -- sh -c "softwareupdate -i -a && shutdown -h now"
```

Doing something like this automatically for all other possible apps is not that easy. You'd have to write some kind of script or daemon that waits in the background, and specifically checks for a finished download. Whether this is even possible—I don't know.

Maybe if you explained more about the reason why you'd want to do this, you'd get better answers.

Comment: Well, I have a slow internet connection so I sometimes out of desperation need to leave the laptop on for the whole night, plugged in. I think the ability to automatically shut it down would open more doors for me (i on't like to leave it on for the night).

Comment: Thanks for the info about Software Updates, the rest I'll try to figure myself.